# how to send json to php file to save on server

Tags: php, javascript

Im developing a javascript/php/ajax application and have stumbled across some problems.

Im confident at javascript and ajax but my php is a little rusty.

My aim is to get a json file from the server, modify it using javascript, and then save this modified json back to the server.

After some research it was obvious that the modified json file must be sent to a php file, this php file will then do the saving.

HOW do i send a json string from javascript to php? OR how do I get the php file to pick up the json variable from the javascript?

im assuming the php will be something like:

```
<?php 
    $json = $_POST["something"];
?>
```

but how do i send or "post" the javascript variable to the php file?

I was thinking about creating a hidden html form, setting a hidden textbox to the json string, then posting the html form

But surely there must be a way without including the html middle man?

Im looking for answer WITHOUT jQuery. Seeing as this is an application i would like a relieve the dependancy of jQuery.

Comment: the setup seems quite strange to me. care to discover some details of the json and purpose of sending it to and fro?

Comment: because my application needs testing in a real world environment so any errors that occur will be saved in a JSON file for me to read through in order to find errors and correct them:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a XMLHttp-Request like this:

```
xmlhttp.open( "POST", url, false );
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(
    'Content-Type',
    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
);
xmlhttp.send("data=yaystuff!")
```

So you can send it. In PHP just get the $_POST['data'] variable and do some json_decode() on it, if you send JSON :)

Comment: hiya. I tried your method. with the xmlhttp.send("data=whatever"); but the php file doesnt seem to respond. For the url i put an absolute url path so the path is correct. And the first line of the php file is <code>header("Location: http://facebook.com");</code> but its not even re-directing. ive tried other code too. Basically the php file isnt even running when i call it through ajax???

Comment: The PHP File has a redirect? Well, you are doing a request, not getting a response. It wouldnt redirect you anywhere. The PHP file would get something like the POST variable and then it should return something, which is for your Javascript again, to use.

Answer (score 2):

The only, as far as I know, proper way to do this is sending data to a file through Ajax, then attaching some POST or GET data.

Example: 
You could send the data in the url as GET:
http://example.com/foo.php?myvalue=cake

And then in the php you'd say:

```
<?php
$yourvalue = $_GET['myvalue'];
// Some code to save it to the database/server
?>
```

Comment: I know how to recieve through ajax via xmlhttp.send(); Is send just the same but with the string argument in the send method? like: xmlhttp.send(jsonString);

Comment: JSON is just a string for PHP as well. So you send this JSON as a string, and on th ePHP side you need to decode it.